# How to enable minimap in Mono Develop?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, add-in

I've seen in some screenshots that is possible to [enable a minimap](https://inorton.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/monodevelop-3/) in mono develop. Someone could please give me an explanation for dummies about how to enable it please? I need to install some extension/package?

My operative system is Xubuntu 15.04 and my mono develop version is 5.9.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

1. Go to Edit > Preferences > Source analysis
2. Check "Enable source analysis of open files"

If you don't find "Source analysis" under preferences, do this:

1. Go to Tools > Complements > Testing
2. Install NUnit support

Then in the orange spot on the top of your scrollbar, do right click and select "Show minimap". You should have it enabled now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MonoDevelop 5.7.1.

To enable the minimap feature, you need to right-click the orange circle in the top right corner of the sourcefile window and select "Show Minimap".

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't see the orange circle. Could you please upload a screenshot? I'm using MonoDevelop 5.9

Comment: Please don't mind the code. But there it is -> [screenshot](http://imgur.com/3rtCHkq)

Comment: I don't know if i have to install any additional package or it has to do with my version but here's how i see my scrollbar -> [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/zR1pLrT.png)